# gimp 2.8 install problem on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

In a terminal,i wrote this command:

```
apt-get install gimp
```

And it returns with this output:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I'm new to ubuntu and been using ubuntu 1 week.

Comment: thank you. adding "sudo" before the "apt-get" command now gimp is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gimp
apt-get clean
```

Comment: You gave him 1€, learn him to make his money :)